# android app is crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

Using Big Nerd Ranch Tutorial Book and I just finished chapter or only have one page left there is some points in quizactivity.java that I'm not sure if I'm supposed to delete.

My quizactivity.java is

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse [] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
       boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

       int messageResId = 0;

       if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
           messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
       } else {
           messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;    
       }

       Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.True_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
                        R.string.correct_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
                        R.string.incorrect_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }); 

        mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            }
        });


                updateQuestion();

            }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quiz, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

My GeoQuiz Manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_quiz.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"   >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="24dp" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/next_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/next_button" />

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/True_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/true_button" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/false_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/false_button" />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My TrueFalse.Java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

public class TrueFalse {
    private int mQuestion;

    private boolean mTrueQuestion;

    public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {
        mQuestion = getQuestion();
        mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    }

    public int getQuestion() {
        return mQuestion;
    }

    public void setQuestion(int question) {
        mQuestion = question;
    }

    public boolean isTrueQuestion() {
        return mTrueQuestion;
    }

    public void setTrueQuestion(boolean trueQuestion) {
        mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace (from logcat) for your crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're getting `ResourceNotFoundException`,

Please note this array of your `QuizActivity`

```
private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse [] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
};
```

The cause starts here,

```
private int mQuestion; // Default Value of this integer is 0

public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {

        mQuestion = getQuestion(); // You're just assigning assigning the value of mQuestion to itself

        mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
}
```

`question` parameter is never been passed to field `mQuestion`.

To fix, you must assign `question` to `mQuestion` variable.

```
public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {

            mQuestion = question;

            mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but hey if you could see problem after changing code with next button that would be great.